# Find the coordinates of three distinct points on the elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am studying elliptic curves. I have an operation that I want to resolve.
$y^2 = x^3 + 8x + 3$ on the ﬁeld $\mathbb {F}_{23}$. And I try to find the coordinates of three distinct points on the curve that are not the inﬁnite points. Can someone help to understand how I should proceed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: `F := GF(23); E:= EllipticCurve([F| 8,3]); E; Points(E);`  http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Comment: Start substituting the values of $x=0,1,2, \ldots, 22$ and find if $y$ exists for these values of $x$. For example with $x=0$, we get $y^2=3 \pmod{23}$. You should check to see if $3$ has a square root modulo $23$. Hint: $(\pm 7)^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{23}$. Thus $(0,7)$ and$(0,16)$ are two points on the curve.

Comment: Thank to Reuns and Anurag. I will try to follow your guides.